# AJAX DATA fetch from XML

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to fetch data from xml but it gives me error do not where is my mistake as i am new here please suggest my PHP code is here

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AJAX PHP FILE</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("cd_catalog.xml");
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('ARTIST');

for ($i=0; $i<=$x->length-1; $i++) {
  //Process only element nodes
  if ($x->item($i)->nodeType==1) {
    if ($x->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue == $q) {
      $y=($x->item($i)->parentNode);
    }
  }
}

$cd=($y->childNodes);

for ($i=0;$i<$cd->length;$i++) { 
  //Process only element nodes
  if ($cd->item($i)->nodeType==1) {
    echo("<b>" . $cd->item($i)->nodeName . ":</b> ");
    echo($cd->item($i)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
    echo("<br>");
  }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and My XML file code is here

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CATALOG>
<CD>
<TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Mujtaba</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Masroor</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Mustafa</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1982</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Murtaza</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD></CATALOG>
```

error snap is here 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4x6z.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small mistake in your XML file, on the last line. It should be `</CATALOG>` and not `<CD></CATALOG>`

Comment: Thanks bro solved> can you please suggest me any book , site to take complete  command on AJAX